# Random Letter Distribution Limitations

Tags: c

I am writing a scrabble program that will randomly generate an array of 7 letters.

this is my code that generates the letters and puts them in the array and it works great.

```
char randomletters (char letters[8], int i){

srand((time(NULL)));


for(i=0; i<7; i++){
    letters[i] = (rand() % 26 + 65);
}


     return letters[8];
}
```

My only issue is figuring out how to limit the number of times a certain letter can appear, using the standard scrabble distribution. Such as 'B' only can appear twice. I was thinking a way of doing it was 26 if statements that counted how many of each letter were there and if it was to much then start over? Seem's like that isn't the best way of doing it though.

Not looking for a code answer, just ideas on how to make it happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention it generates only capital letters, and I am working in C.

Comment: it would probably be easier to keep an array of letters you want to use, then compute a random index into that array.

Comment: @chris unfortunately you can't do that in C.

Comment: Counting the number of times each letter appeared and re-generating letter if it's already over-used might not be very elegant solution, but it is the simplest one, and actually quite efficient on 7-letter words.

Comment: @KingsIndian, Oops, my bad. There are lots of ways to shuffle up a hand, but that's the one I like. I didn't realize the category. I suppose that becomes more work when you have to make your own shuffling function :p.

Comment: Also, it allowes you to remove the "consumed" letters from the array (by swapping with the last array element (and lowering the maximal index) The Yates shuffle only has to be done at the beginning, and cost N-1 swaps. (and is not necessary)

Answer (score 1):

```
char array[] = "AAAAAAAAABBCCD";

unsigned remaining = sizeof array;


int get_a_letter(void)
{
  unsigned idx;
  int sample;

  if (!remaining) return EOF;

  idx = urnd(remaining);
  sample = array[idx] ;
  array [idx] = array [--remaining];
  array [remaining] = sample; // @Note:1
  return sample;
}
```

`urnd(xxx)` is a function that should return a random value between 0 and (xxx-1), *inclusive*.

Update

@Note1: this statement is not necessary for drawing a random letter, but it helps for the next round: resetting `remaining = sizeof array;` will suffice to start over. (the array will be scrambled, but all the initial letters are still present)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of struct to keep a letter and the number of times it can be used. Randomly choose a number between 0 and 25, if the chosen cell has a count >0 add the letter to the rack decrease the letter count, repeat until the rack counts 7 tiles, repeat the whole think until less than 7 letters are left.

Comment: I'm not very skilled with using structs, but couldn't I do that same idea but with just an array of all the possible letters? ex, A A A A A A A A A B B C C... and so on?

Comment: yes sure, say you have an array letters[N], set MAX=N-1 then randomely choose a letter betwen 0 and MAX, swap it with the letter in position MAX, decrease MAX, repeat until your rack has 7 letters, repeat until MAX<7 after a rack completion ... I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Yes, having an array of all possible letters like this would actually give you a better result.  This is because with the two answers given so far, you have an equal change of choosing an A as a Z even though there are 7 A's and only 1 Z.

Comment: @wildplasser oops ... didn't notice ! sorry ... will let you add your answer.

Comment: Thank you all thats helpful I'll make that array. One question though, is there a way to delete that specific letter I choose so it doesn't get picked again?

Comment: The other way (having cells with value+count of remaining) is much more work, but can be needed when (some of) the counts are very high. That technique was used in Megahal/Wakkerbot to take a weighted sample-word from a list (up to 100K items) of words. The trick is to remember the total count, and move the higher counts to the beginning of the array. (the words have an expected powerlaw distribution)

Comment: Ryan: it has already been said: pick a random slot, and consume it by swapping it with the highest slot (and lowering the maximum allowable index for the next draw)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "highest slot"

Comment: Highest slot is the  `[ --remaining ]` in my answer.